# Issue with scipy quad integration in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I'm quite new to python so I'm hoping my wording makes sense. I'm currently attempting to model a set of equations that require the product of an integration to be multiplied by a float. I'm getting a Nan output from the integration output alone and I don't know why that is my code is below:

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as sp
import scipy as sci
from scipy import integrate
import math
from sympy.functions import coth
Tc = 9.25
Tb = 7.2
t = Tb / Tc
Temperature = []
Temp1=[]
Temp0=[]
D=[]
d = []
D1=[]
d1 = []
n = 2*10**-6
L = 100*10**-9
W = 80*10**-9
a = 3*10**-2
s1 = W/ (2*n)
y1 = (L+(W/2)) / (2*n)
x0 = 0.015
r0 = 2*x0
s2 = r0 / n
y0 = (x0 / n)/1000000
print x0, y0, y1
A = ((W/n)**2) *(sp.kv(0, s1)+(math.pi / 2)*sp.kv(1,s1)*coth(y1))
B = ((W/n)**2) *(sp.iv(0, s1)+(math.pi / 2)*sp.iv(1,s1)*coth(y1))
print A, B
def t1(t):
    return  (t**-1)*sp.kv(0, s2)
def t2(t):
    return (t**-1)*sp.iv(0, s2)
print t2
Fk2 =(math.pi**-2) * integrate.quad(t1, s1, s2, full_output=False)[0]
FI2 =(math.pi**-2) * integrate.quad(t2, s1, s2, full_output=False)[0]
print Fk2 , #FI2
r1 = 0.0
while r1 < y1:
    #C0 = sp.kv(0,s2)*(1 + (A*FI2)-(B*Fk2))/A
    #print C0
    #D_ = 1 - B*Fk2 - A*Fk2*sp.iv(1, s1) / sp.kv(1, 1)
    #print D_
    r1 += 0.0001
    j = -1*r1
    D.append(r1)
    d.append(j)
    #T = Tb + (Tc - Tb) * (sp.kv(0,s1) + (math.pi /2)* sp.kv(1, s1)*coth(r1))*(1- D_ * math.cosh(y1)) * (C0*A)
    #Temp0.append(T)
    #print Temp0, r1
```

The main culprit seems to be the the modified bessel function in equation FI2 sp.iv(t2, s1) that returns an Nan value but the other equation results Fk2 gives 0. for some time I was getting the following error:

```
IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents the requested tolerance from being achieved. The error may be underestimated. warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
```

but that has stopped and now I only get 0.0 and Nan. Any help is really appreciated I'm quite lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value for s2 is rather large (15000.0). So, when you evaluate the [Bessel Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) at s2 you get zero:

```
>>> sp.kv(0, 15000.0)
0.0
```

So your function t1 always returns zero, making the integral zero.